# Why is my next-auth google/github signin Button not working even though i Did all the steps right?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

[My project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ad6.png)
[Github link-](https://github.com/yashbudhia/Amazon-Price-Tracker)
I followed the steps by reading next-auth documentation.
Wrapped my layout.tsx file in  too,
still when i put signIn() method in my button -

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => signIn("github")}
        className="w-64 h-16 rounded shadow-sm bg-blue-300 hover:bg-slate-700 text-white"
      >
        Sign in via Google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

The button wont redirect anywhere for some reason,
Any help from the experts?
I did the exact same thing in a new application and it works but in this application it doesnt for some reason.(This is a fairly big application and i am puttting authentication at last )

I want the button to redirect to Github oauth provider but it doesnt?

Comment: It's possible that you already authenticated with github, then it might immediately set the token from the previous session without redirecting. Try clearing your cookies and look at the dev tools to see what requests it's making. Check if you have any next-auth session cookies.